# How to pre-processed text to keep dashed words?

Tags: text-mining, tokenization, regex

I'm working on compiling reviews for movies and analysing it in Orange. I've found that words like "r-rated" get converted to "r" and "rated". I've messed around a bit with the pre-processed text widget, but nothing seems to be able to output "r-rated" as a single token.

I assume it has to do with regexp, but I'm not sure what I could write to keep dashed words. Can anyone help with this?

[Here's an image of what the word-cloud looks like](https://imgur.com/od5ei6E)

Comment: A crappy workaround could be to remove all the "-" from the text.